# IOS X,Y coordinates from image

Tags: ios, swift, image, coordinates, gestures

I am new to IOS Programming coming from Android I am Trying to get The X,Y Coordinates for a double tap on the screen but I need the coords in relation to the image itself and not the image view.

This is my view controller code

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var firstPass:String!
var secondPass:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=20.0
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapAction:"))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=2
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imageView
}

func tapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.locationInView(self.imageView)
    let Z1:String = String(touchPoint.x)
    let Z2:String = String(touchPoint.y)
    print( "YES It Works X= " + Z1 + " Y= " + Z2)

    }
    print( "It Works X= " + Z1 + " Y= " + Z2)
}


}
```

This works ok and when double tapped it prints the coordinates

The Image is a PNG inside an Imageview which in turn is inside a Scrollview

The PNG has the dimensions 6400px X 4100px but if I double tap at the bottom right of the image view instead of getting 6400,4100 I get 478,415 so it is obviously using the coords from the image view

In android I would use PointF to get these

Is there an equivalent in Swift

I am using Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0

Any Help is appreciated

Mark

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used scroll views, and I'm away from my computer, so I can't test, but I believe you ought to add self.scrollView.contentOffset to touchPoint.

Comment: Its because you get the point coordinate and not the pixel coordinate. You would need to translate this yourself. Use the size of the image (px), and the devices screen size (or the imgview framesize) and calculate it.

Comment: Thanks for the help any ideas or pointer to places where I can see how this is done also how would it handle different size of devices and resoloution for different devices as this is a universal app

Comment: Matt When you say its been a while since you used scrollviews would you know if there is a better way of achieving what I am Trying to do which is to display a large bitmap on screen and get the coordinates of the double tap in pixel coordinates of the said image itself? I need this so I can then work out if a certain area of image (like a hotspot in HTML)is tapped  any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture following two things :

1. Image size
2. Frame size (i.e. imageView size)

With this, you need to calculate the actual touched point.

Following code might help you :

```
 var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.photoImageView)

 touchPoint.x = touchPoint.x *  (photoImageView.image?.size.width)! / photoImageView.frame.width
 touchPoint.y = touchPoint.y *  (photoImageView.image?.size.height)! / photoImageView.frame.height

 print("Touched point (\(touchPoint.x), \(touchPoint.y)")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is useful for getting the click position relative to the image view, but doesn't provide the position of the click relative to the image itself. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: The above won't work for images that don't fill the entire imageView.